# Gradient Position in HTML5 Canves

Tags: javascript, html, css

i am building dynamic report in html5 Canves i want to add 2 color gradient in html5.
My code is below

```
var gradient = content.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 30);  
gradient.addColorStop(0, "rgb(255, 255, 255)");  
gradient.addColorStop(1, "rgb(0, 0, 0)");  

content.save();  
content.fillStyle = gradient;  
content.fillRect(0, 0, 100, 30);  
content.restore();
```

It's Look fine but When i change position of box gradient come flat see code below.

```
var gradient = content.createLinearGradient(0, 100, 0, 30);  
gradient.addColorStop(0, "rgb(255, 255, 255)");  
gradient.addColorStop(1, "rgb(0, 0, 0)");  

content.save();  
content.fillStyle = gradient;  
content.fillRect(0, 100, 100, 30);  
content.restore();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

createLinearGradient takes x1, x2, y1, y2, and makes a gradient from (x1, y1) to (x2, y2).

fillRect is different. It takes x, y, w, h, and makes a rectangle from (x, y) with width w and height h.

The code you have now creates an upside down gradient from (0, 100) to (0, 30), and tries to apply it to a rectangle that starts at (0, 100), and ends at (100, 130) because it is 100 wide and 30 high. You're seeing a solid colour because the gradient is being drawn outside of your fill rectangle.

The easy fix is to tweak where your gradient ends:

```
var gradient = content.createLinearGradient(0, 100, 0, 130);
gradient.addColorStop(0, "rgb(255, 255, 255)");
gradient.addColorStop(1, "rgb(0, 0, 0)");

content.save();
content.fillStyle = gradient;
content.fillRect(0, 100, 100, 30);
content.restore();
```

Remember, don't just play with the numbers until they look right. Always read the docs and make sure you know what parameters you're sending :)

Answer (score 0):

You may try **[Gradient Generator](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/)**.

Hope this helps.